# Source navigation is not showing when working with external/ remote git repository in visual studio online

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

Consider I have a git repository hosted in Bitbucket. I have added this reference using following way.

> Serttings > Services > External Git
>   [image]
>   Now when I am going to create a build it is not showing source navigation. But when we use visual studio git it shows source navigation like following
>   [image]

But navigation is missing for external git
[image]

**Is it known issue or I am missing any configuration that’s why it is not showing source navigation?**

Comment: Still waiting for valuable response.. I am also expecting help from @Eddie - MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is by design, you just can specify the file manually (relative path and Wildcards can be used, e.g. ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1.sln).

I submitted a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16468180-select-file-directly-in-vsts-tfs-vnext-build-with) that you could vote.

Comment: Thank you for adding it to user voice.